# C solution, can someone explain this code to me?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

My C++ teacher provided a solution to a problem we had and there's one part that I can't understand what's happening. Can someone explain to me? m and n are being read in from a text file to define the size of an array.

```
for (int row=0; row < m; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) {
        if (field[row][col] =='*') {

            ctr[row - 1][col - 1]++;
            ctr[row - 1][col]++;
            ctr[row - 1][col + 1]++;
            ctr[row][col - 1]++;
            ctr[row][col + 1]++;
            ctr[row + 1][col - 1]++;
            ctr[row + 1][col]++;
            ctr[row + 1][col + 1]++;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tell us about the problem for which you wrote this code.

Comment: It may help if you write the problem you had to solve.

Comment: what is ctr? is this some magic?

Comment: Looks like minesweeper

Comment: Is this a "game of life" type thing?

Answer (score 4):

It will increases one the value of all squares around stars (`*`) in a matrix.

First it searches for a `*`, then increases the value of all 8 squares around the star.

Assume a part of matrix `field` is like below.

```
     |    |  
+----+----+---+
     |  * |  
+----+----+---+
     |    |
```

and `ctr` is like below

```
   1 |  1 | 1
+----+----+---+
   1 |  1 | 1
+----+----+---+
   1 |  1 | 1
```

`ctr` will be

```
   2 |  2 | 2
+----+----+---+
   2 |  1 | 2
+----+----+---+
   2 |  2 | 2
```

The logic is as above. But be careful of access violation when a star is near boundaries.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Thank you, I was killing myself with my notepad++ ! :-)))

Comment: In my answers I generally draw figures. If you wants to draw a image  you can use [**dia**](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/) Its again very simple tool.

Answer (score 1):

You have two 2D arrays `ctr` and `field`. Some fields of `field` contains `*`

Assume this 2D array

```
field        ---->row
       . | .  | .
    +----+----+---+
 |     . |  * | .
 |  +----+----+---+
 c     . |  . | .
 o
 l
```

will give

```
   ctr        ---->row
       1 | 1  | 1
   | +----+----+---+
   |   1 |  * | 1
   c +----+----+---+
   o   1 |  1 | 1
   l
```

The code:

```
for (int row=0; row < m; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) {
        if (field[row][col] =='*') { //Assume center of the field array contains *

            ctr[row - 1][col - 1]++; //incr elemnt at previous row, previous col
            ctr[row - 1][col]++;     //incr elemnt on previous row, same col
            ctr[row - 1][col + 1]++; //incr elemnt on previous row, next col
            ctr[row][col - 1]++;     //incr elemnt on same row, previous col
            ctr[row][col + 1]++;     //incr elemnt on same row, next col
            ctr[row + 1][col - 1]++; //incr elemnt on next row, previous col
            ctr[row + 1][col]++;     //incr elemnt on next row, same col
            ctr[row + 1][col + 1]++; //incr elemnt on next row, next col

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Grijesh Thanks :) I always wondered how ppl posted so nicely made graphs :P Now I know

Comment: actually I came to know about this today only...Otherwise I myself draw by hand :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks for a * in the "Field" matrix.

Then it takes the position of the *, and adds 1 to the values around *'s position in the "ctr" matrix.